# How come I cannot run Art Generator?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, torch

Using `Colab` at the time. I start running `Art Generator` in `Colab`. It always gives me the following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-b113744af221> in <module>()
      4 
      5 for prompt in text_prompts:
----> 6   device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
      7   print('Using device:', device)
      8   if textos:

NameError: name 'torch' is not defined
```

Please note that I'm not a programmer and I barely understand what a code is.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. In order for us to help you we need a bit more information. Namely you need to add a minimal reproducible example for us to use to help you debug. Refer  to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. So in summary please add the code that is causing this error

Comment: what is `Art Generator in Colab`? Where is your code?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: did you install module `torch`? `pip install torch` ?